# BatchElements() works on DirectRunner but not in DataflowRunner when a Reshuffle() is added before that

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In Apache beam, `BatchElements()` groups elements into batches of a specified size of 100 when running with DirectRunner. But same code on DataflowRunner groups elements into batches of 1. I have `Reshuffle()` before `BatchElements()`.

Without the `Reshuffle()` it works as expected on both runners.

```html
                p
                | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription)
                | "Parse as List" >> Map(lambda element: json.loads(element))
                | "Flatten" >> FlatMap(lambda elements: elements)
                | Reshuffle()
                | "Typed Element" >> ParDo(TypedElement())
                | "Batch Typed Element"
                >> BatchElements(
                    min_batch_size=50, max_batch_size=50, target_batch_duration_secs=None
                )
```

Has anybody been in a similar problem? Any suggestions would be very much appreciated! I've been banging my head on this for a few days now.

Comment: Reshuffle uses ReshufflePerKey and is marked as experimental. BatchElements is "A Transform that batches elements for amortized processing." What kind of logic are you trying to apply here? If you want to explicitly control some logic for every 100 element per key per window, you probably should use stateful processing: https://beam.apache.org/blog/stateful-processing/

Comment: While Reshuffle is marked as experimental. Dataflow explicitly supports it and is a recommended way to prevent fusion. Without reshuffle, dataflow fuses all the steps and workers don't scale.

BatchElements() is used because elements don't have keys. We need to batch it for fetching HTML async so that we can increase throughput. 

The expected behavior is, a batch of elements (~50) get distributed parallel DoFn between 100s of workers.

Comment: I'm not sure whether BatchElements is the right approach here since you don't have control of the batch. Here is an example batching elements: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/ml-inference-in-dataflow-pipelines. Look for the `Batching through state and timers` and it seems that it naturally requires shuffle.

Comment: Thanks for the resource! We opted to use Reshuffle after batching the elements. We have good batches and nice parallelism there.